# Debug Draw in andengine

Tags: android, debugging, box2d, andengine, draw

I am trying for debug draw in andengine but till now i did not got solution for debug draw for Box2d in andengine.if you have any solution please kindly share your solution.

EDIT: I need to visualize physics(box2d) objects in Andengine. I thought of doing this using DebugDraw functionality. But I cant get it to work. Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific... what are you doing so far and what is the problem you are having with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [AndEnginePhysicsBox2DDebugRenderer](http://code.google.com/p/andenginephysicsbox2ddebugrenderer/).

It's simple, but it supports all the Box2D shapes (CircleShape and PolygonShape).

Comment: Thank for your help. it was working fine for me. But i am unable to check in that source code simply i downloaded each java file separately and included in my project.

But i am unable to fill the physics body. i am getting only outline for the physics body.

Comment: What problems do you run into? Also, it's meant to be very simple, so it only draws the outlines right now.